# Q: Creating a combined plot based on a ts object

Tags: time-series, q

R beginner here.

I have created a dataframe (called combined_ts2) based on a dataset I was given.[See this link for the dataframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEp1d.png)
Based on the dataframe a made [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB3Gh.png) ts object (find code at bottom of post).

I am supposed to make a plot based on the TS object. I'm thinking this can be achieved with a `ts.plot` function, but I can't figure out how to use this function.

The result I want is to get a bar graph for capacity and a line graph for fixtures. Does anyone know how to achieve this, and if I can actually achieve this from a ts object?

**dput for dataframe**

`structure(list(week = c(26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48), capacity = c(45000L, 
39000L, 495500L, 855300L, 1318300L, 1301885L, 8211550L, 18515400L, 
32282950L, 31568400L, 35410200L, 29867500L, 34809050L, 36420050L, 
33960520L, 33987550L, 33465500L, 24599000L, 11597000L, 4553000L, 
1375000L, 545000L), fixtures = c(2L, 4L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 29L, 
161L, 338L, 393L, 405L, 439L, 386L, 442L, 406L, 413L, 421L, 326L, 
180L, 84L, 23L, 6L, 3L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -22L))`

**Time series code**

`weekly_timeseries <- ts(combined_ts2, start=c(2019,26), frequency = 52)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You're most likely to get help if you post a sample of your data with `dput`, not an image (we can't copy-and-paste from an image into R).

Comment: Thanks, @A.S.K. !
I included the `dput`. Just to make sure, this is how it is reproducible?

Comment: Does the plot have to be generated from a ts object, or does it work for you to use the original dataframe?  If you can use the dataframe, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35071209/10898875) has a nice summary of how to do bar and line graphs for time series using `ggplot2`.